# Proving a strange vector inequality in the euclidean space

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

It seems to hold the following inequality in an euclidean reference frame $(x,y,z)$:
$$\overrightarrow{U}\cdot\overrightarrow{U}\ge\sqrt{2}\left(\Omega_x+\Omega_y\right)$$
where:
$$\overrightarrow{U}\equiv(a,b,c), (a,b,c\gt0)$$
$$\overrightarrow{\Omega}=\overrightarrow{V}\times\overrightarrow{W}$$
and:
$$\overrightarrow{V}\equiv(0,a,b),\overrightarrow{W}\equiv(0,-c,b)$$
Is there any way to give a proof of that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. The right-side of your inequality is a vector if $\times$ means cross product. Does it mean something else here?

Comment: Start by developing the inequality using the given definitions of the vectors !

Comment: @Casteels: right. I forgot to put $|V\times U|$

Comment: @Casteels: I corrected the question, sorry.

Comment: That's ok of course. But now what does $\Omega_x$ and $\Omega_y$ mean? The first two entries of $\overrightarrow{\Omega}=(ab+bc,0,0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking if it is true that $$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq \sqrt{2}(ab+bc).$$

Well, \begin{align*} a^2+b^2+c^2-\sqrt{2}(ab+bc) & =\left(a-\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + \left(c-\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 \geq 0.
\end{align*}

By the way, notice that your inequality is true for any $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is this inequality true also for negative values of $a,b,c$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was implying in the last sentence. And assuming I interpreted your notation correctly.